# Why is list not bound?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got a very simple ASP.NET MVC (5.2.4.0) app with the code below. I can not find the reason for *model.Addresses* being empty when the form is posted to the *[HttpPost]* method. Can someone please help me? For what I can see my code matches answers to similar questions here on StackOverflow.

**HomeController.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication2.Controllers {

    public class IndexViewModel {

    public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Address> Addresses;

        public IndexViewModel()
        {
            Addresses = new List<Address>();
        }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new IndexViewModel();

            model.Addresses = new List<Address>();
            model.Addresses.Add(new Address() { Id = "1", Name = "A1" });
            model.Addresses.Add(new Address() { Id = "2", Name = "A2" });

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshml:**

```
@model WebApplication2.Controllers.IndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{

    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)

    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Addresses.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Addresses[i].Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Addresses[i].Id)
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
}
```

Comment: `public List<Address> Addresses;` => you're declaring a field instead of a list property. Usually the viewmodel bounds with properties, try using `{ get; set; }` property modifier.

Comment: Tetsuya Yamamoto, thanks...you are the best! That was a sneaky one :)

Answer (score 0):

As [Tetsuya Yamamoto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6378815/tetsuya-yamamoto) mention in the comments above the error was due to Addresses being a public field and not a property.

```
 public List<Address> Addresses;
```

should be changed into

```
 public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please declare Addresses as property like below as you declared it as public field not property so it can not hold the value you assigned.

```
 public List<Address> Addresses{get;set;};
```